# How to fix "Maximum recursion depth reached" error in the below code?

Tags: python, json, tail-recursion

I have written a script in python that does the following operations:

1. Takes a folder path as input that may contain many child directories with .json files in them
2. Loads the .json files from all folders one by one and read each file line by line, parse them into key, value list and writes to excel file.

This script works fine when I run it from command prompt. But I want to share it to my team as an executable file, I have used pyinstaller to convert it to an exe. That is when I'm getting the error

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

I found that the error is because of a function that is tail-recursive. I'm new to python so I'm finding it difficult to rewrite this function. Please suggest ways to rewrite this tail-recursive function.

```
import json
import codecs
import itertools
import os
import sys
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
import dateutil.parser
from openpyxl import Workbook

def load_json_from_directories(root_path, cur_path, asset_code):
    for filename in os.listdir(cur_path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(cur_path, filename)):
            if os.path.splitext(filename)[1] == '.json':
                print('Processing...'+filename)
                load_json_line(os.path.join(cur_path, filename), asset_code)
            else:
                print('Not a json file! Skipping...'+filename)
        elif os.path.isdir(os.path.join(cur_path, filename)):
            load_json_from_directories(root_path, os.path.join(cur_path, filename), asset_code)
        else:
            sys.exit("Should never reach here.")
```

Comment: Use `os.walk` instead of recursion.

Comment: @chepner I still get the same error after using os.walk.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing this manually, you could use existing functionality:

```py
from pathlib import Path

for json_path in Path('.').glob('**/*.json'):
    # code to handle jsons here
    print(json_path)
```

Comment: Again, this works fine in the command prompt, but still getting the same error **RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded** when I use pyinstaller to convert it to exe.

Comment: Could you check what your recursion limit is by running this "sys.getrecursionlimit()"? Why do you have such nested directories?

Comment: "sys.getrecursionlimit()" gives 1500. Such nested directories are because the data is downloaded from Microsoft Azure blob storage, where the directory tree is like "blobname->2019->02->08->00..23" (24 folders for each hour)